# How much time do I have to wait once exceeded the 10 TPS with the Mule 4 Object Store V2?

Tags: mule, mule-esb, persistent-object-store

**Background**

As per the MuleSoft docs on [Object Store V2 FAQ's](https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store/osv2-faq), I am aware of the free tier Object-store TPS Vs The Purchased SKU rate limit.

If OSV2 SKU is purchased you get a - `Rate limit of 100 TPS`, else it will be `10 TPS`.

I have not purchased any *OSV2 SKU*.

---

### **Problem statement**

I have a requirement to use *OSV2* in my project, but I constantly keep hitting the threshold of 10 TPS, ultimately getting a `429 rate limit exceeded`.

To over come this, I planned to use Until-successful scope, and then have the Object-store inside it. I was hoping to wait a while and retry.

The documentation says, "`Once reached the rate limit, and after subsequently getting a 429 response, you have to wait for a time`".

> My question, How much time do I have to wait to move into the next window ?

I waited for 30 seconds before my next retry, but still I am getting the same response.